# How can I put alt attribute in site logo on Drupal?

Tags: drupal, themes, alt

I'm trying to put this code on page.tpl.php:

```
<a href="<?php print check_url($front_page); ?>" title="<?php print t('Home'); ?>">
  <img src="<?php print $site_logo; ?>" alt="<?php print t('Home'); ?>" />
</a>
```

but it's not working.

I put on theme-setting:

```
form['logo']['settings']['logo_alt_text'] = array(
       '#type' => 'textfield',
       '#title' => t('Alternative text for to custom logo'),
       '#default_value' =>  'MI TEXTO',
       '#description' => t('A description of the custom logo if it conveys meaning. Otherwise it will assume the site name.'),
     );
```

and I goy a new field for "alternative text", but after this text doesn't appear in the logo.

Please, can you help me? Thank you.

Comment: I goy = I got. sorry!

Comment: Do you mean a tooltip (which gets displayed when hovering over the image with a mouse), or alternative text (for user agents without image support, e.g., screen reader users, search engines, …)?

Answer (score 0):

In your first block of code from you page.tpl.php, I see you have 'hard-coded' the img alt attribute to be 'Home'. Just change that text to whatever you want, such as 'My Company'.

```
<img src="<?php print $site_logo; ?>" alt="<?php print t('My Company'); ?>" />
```

Editing your "theme-setting" - which I have no idea what it actually is, but I will presume you mean template.php - is pointless, as it is not able to change any of the properties/attributes of this image. The `$site_logo` only outputs the url to the image, such as `www.example.com/logo.jpg`

I hope you have set up your own theme in sites/all/themes, which is either a 'stand-alone' theme, or a sub-theme of an existing theme such as bartik. Perhaps you put the first code block in the wrong page.tpl.php. If you made a sub-theme of bartik, it needs to be in the sub-themes page.tpl.php, which will override the default bartik page.tpl.php.